# Identify What am I ? - Riddle 1

Tags: riddle

I do not like to hear from you,
But you are pleased to meet me only when you need me.

I am happy not be working.
When I have work, I start screaming.

I can be annoying to many regulars.
But am inspiring for little ones.

You can reach me if you need me,
Hope you still like me if you don't.

---

My first ever try to create a riddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is

> An ambulance or fire truck.

I do not like to hear from you, But you are pleased to meet me only when you need me.

> Hearing from me means something bad happened, but I will be pleased when I get help.

I am happy not be working. When I have work, I start screaming.

> Sirens.

I can be annoying to many regulars. But am inspiring for little ones.

> The loud noises of the siren are annoying to adults, but especially fire trucks are inspiring to kids.

You can reach me if you need me, Hope you still like me if you don't.

> You can call the ambulance whenever there's an emergency.

Comment: Congratulations, Glad someone got the correct answer. Was worried the clues might not be enough.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing it's a

> bell, gong or other ringing device

```
I do not like to hear from you, But you are pleased to meet me only when you need me.
```

> You may need to hear the bell during a boxing match or a boring class

```
I am happy not be working. When I have work, I start screaming.
```

> It makes noises when it works. It is still otherwise.

```
I can be annoying to many regulars. But am inspiring for little ones.
```

> Normally most people hate ringing sounds. Children however love noises of all sorts and often enjoy the sound of it.

```
You can reach me if you need me, Hope you still like me if you don't.
```

> Possibly a reference to the religious symbolism of bells.

Comment: quite close, but not quite what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my stab at it

> An alarm clock

```
I do not like to hear from you, But you are pleased to meet me only when you need me.
```

> I hate hearing my alarm go off... But I'm always thankful when it goes off when it's supposed to

```
I am happy not be working. When I have work, I start screaming.
```

> When it reaches the appropriate time, it goes off. Otherwise it is silent

```
I can be annoying to many regulars. But am inspiring for little ones.
```

> Every day at the same time it goes off. Kids on the other hand, see each day as a new adventure.

```
You can reach me if you need me, Hope you still like me if you don't.
```

> I always struggle to turn off my alarm when it goes off. But I am still grateful when I get up on time

Comment: A close one. Good reasoning. Not the answer I have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> Songs

Whenever we are not pleased, songs will make us pleased

> I do not like to hear from you, But you are pleased to meet me only when you need me.

Until play the songs, it will be happy, once started it may get scream

> I am happy not be working. When I have work, I start screaming.

It can be annoying for some , but some good music may be an inspiring

> I can be annoying to many regulars. But am inspiring for little ones.

Its  so easy as to be reached or to be heard whenever we need

> You can reach me if you need me, Hope you still like me if you don't.